# How to check if column is exist in Linq join query c#?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Hi I am running one Linq query to join three tables. below is the query...

```
answerText = ds.Tables[0];
questionAvg = ds.Tables[1];
interviews = ds.Tables[2];

var data = from at in answerText.AsEnumerable()
           join qa in questionAvg.AsEnumerable() on at.Field<int>("ID") equals qa.Field<int>("DealerID")
           join inter in interviews.AsEnumerable() on at.Field<int>("ID") equals inter.Field<int>("DealerID")
           select new
           {
               DealerID = at.Field<int>("ID"),
               DealerName = at.Field<string>("Name"),
               AnswerText1 = at.Field<int?>("12"),                           
               AnswerText2 = at.Field<int?>("8"),
               AnswerText3 = at.Field<int?>("4"),
               AnswerText4 = at.Field<int?>("0"),
               AnswerText5 = at.Field<int?>("-4"),
               Rank = qa.Field<Int64?>("Rank"),
               Average = qa.Field<decimal?>("Average"),
               N = inter.Field<int?>("N")
           };
```

now sometimes answerText datatable will only have column 12 and 8.., so it is missing columns 4 0 -4. how should i avoid that column check in above query and just provide 0 there.

Comment: do you get exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking about, but I assumed you need `AnswerText` properties to be `int` not `int?`. And they should be set to `0` when item is not present. You can use `??` operator:

```
var data = from at in answerText.AsEnumerable()
           join qa in questionAvg.AsEnumerable() on at.Field<int>("ID") equals qa.Field<int>("DealerID")
           join inter in interviews.AsEnumerable() on at.Field<int>("ID") equals inter.Field<int>("DealerID")
           select new
           {
               DealerID = at.Field<int>("ID"),
               DealerName = at.Field<string>("Name"),
               AnswerText1 = at.Field<int?>("12") ?? 0,                           
               AnswerText2 = at.Field<int?>("8") ?? 0,
               AnswerText3 = at.Field<int?>("4") ?? 0,
               AnswerText4 = at.Field<int?>("0") ?? 0,
               AnswerText5 = at.Field<int?>("-4") ?? 0,
               Rank = qa.Field<Int64?>("Rank"),
               Average = qa.Field<decimal?>("Average"),
               N = inter.Field<int?>("N")
           };
```

Comment: My question is there is uncertainity about the columns in answerText datatable. in some condition it is not giving me column 4 , 0 , -4. so  how to avoid that?